# Sorting array by numeric field in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to sort an array of objects by a field that holds numeric value. And this console output is the result of calling:

`console.log(_.sortBy( d, 'userid' ));`

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
count: "6"
name: "Andrey"
userid: "1234"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
count: "9"
name: "Lucas"
userid: "1337"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
count: "30"
name: "M"
userid: "7800"
```

And it looks fine, just as I expect it to happen.

However when I call this:

`console.log(_.sortBy( d, 'count' ));`

Instead of seeing array of order count 6, count 9, count 30, I see this:

```
Array[3]
0: Object
count: "30"
name: "M"
userid: "7800"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
count: "6"
name: "Andrey"
userid: "1234"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
count: "9"
name: "Lucas"
userid: "1337"
```

Can anyone help me understand what is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see any numeric values. They're all strings. `"9"` is different from `9`, especially when it comes to comparisons

Comment: And it is sorting it correctly, "30" (the "3") is before "6", which is before "9".

Comment: You got lucky with your sort by userid, in that they're also alphabetically ascending order in addition to numerical ascending order.  also put a userid in there with the value of `"7"` and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt(obj.count)` before you sort.

Comment: I used this function when adding elements to my array. Thank you for an useful answer.